# Apache Ant: Trying to use map lists to arguments using nested for loops. What should I REALLY be doing?

Tags: ant

So, I've got a list of ${locales} and ${externs} and I'm trying to do this. It isn't working. Ant says that `java doesn't support the nested "for" element.` I suspect my approach is wrong. How should I be trying to do this?

```
<for list="${locales}" param="locale">
  <sequential>
    <java jar="whatever.jar" fork="true">
      <for list="${externs}" param="extern-file">
        <arg line='-f "--externs=${extern_dir}/@{extern-file}"' />
      </for>
      <arg line="... more stuff" />
    </java>
  </sequential>
</for>
```

Comment: Are you trying to run whatever.jar once for each extern-file, or once for each locale with multiple -f --externs=[file] arguments?

Comment: The latter. (comments must be at least 15 characters in length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ant [command-line `line` args](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg) support prefixes and suffixes, which might do the trick for this.

If `${externs}` is a comma-separted list you'll need to make it space-separated, perhaps using the ant-contrib [`propertyregex` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html).

In outline:

```
<propertyregex property="externs.arg"
               input="${externs}"
               regexp="," replace=" " />

<for list="${locales}" param="locale">
  <sequential>
    <java jar="whatever.jar" fork="true">
      <arg line="${externs.arg}"
           prefix='-f "--externs=${extern_dir}/'
           suffix='"' />
      <arg line="... more stuff" />
    </java>
  </sequential>
</for>
```

Comment: Prefixes are a new feature in Ant 1.8, no? ... (stuck on 1.7, unless I spend half a day debugging why the build breaks under v1.8. not a hypothetical, either)

Comment: @fennec - Yes, they are since 1.8.  I did put together an answer that used the pathconvert task, but I deleted it!  When I have time later I will repost.  The basic idea was to, before the for loop, use a pathconvert task to generate the arg line.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some alternative options you could consider.

1. Implement a custom Ant task to do what you need.
2. If you own the Java code you are invoking, update it to be more friendly to your requirements, e.g.

   2.1. Passing list of locales and externs.

   2.2. Accepting input from a file or standard input (both of which you could write to from Ant)
3. If you don't own the Java code, implement your own script or Java code to provide an adapter from something easy to pass from Ant to the required args of the target.